# Identify if email was sent on email client invoked with Blackberry Invoke API

Tags: email, blackberry, invoke

I'm developing an application that allows users to email some information like conference call details. I'm using invoke API to open up a email client with the information pre-filled so as to give user freedom to add more content and choose his own recipients. The requirement is he join/not joins the conference call once he sends the invite.

However, I would want to give him the option to join or not join only if he has sent an invite.

**Any way I can know that he has sent an email using the client.**

I'm not sure I want to use Transport api as I'm not aware of the recipients. Also I'am not aware and sure if I want to search sent items(programatically?) as I won't be co-relate the right message(since user could have altered the subject and body content)

Thanks,
Dakshina

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to sent messages and check if the use has sent this one.

But it is only a listener to the action "Sent". I once lose some time to figure out that if there is a network problem and your message is not really sent, you cannot be notify when it is really sent.

Have a look:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/SendListener.html